# how to update a value of a dict withing a loop into a list of dict

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

As I am stuck, I need some help. I want to update a value of a dict in a list of dict (ideally, I don't want to create another list)

Under an Ansible playbook, I have a variable declared:

```
a:
  - id: 'test1id'
    name: 'test1name'
    description: ''
  - id: 'test2id'
    name: 'test2name'
    description: 'init'
  - id: 'test3id'
    name: 'test3name'
    description: 'init3'
```

I have a task that loop into "a" should update the description.

```
- name: Update description in a
  when: a is defined
  set_fact:
    a: "{{ item | combine({'description': new_description}) }}"
  vars:
    new_description: "{{ item.description + "test" + item.id }}"
  loop: a
```

Expected result:

```
a:
  - id: 'test1id'
    name: 'test1name'
    description: 'test test1id'
  - id: 'test2id'
    name: 'test2name'
    description: 'init test test2id'
  - id: 'test3id'
    name: 'test3name'
    description: 'init3 test test3id'
```

Actual result:

```
a:
  - id: 'test3id'
    name: 'test3name'
    description: 'init3 test test3id'
```

Looks like I'm missing something, I just have the last item. I also tried other format, but that never give me the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done is right.
There were some errors, but I think it was caused by a typo, like `loop: "{{ a }}"` and spaces around the word `test` here `new_description: '{{ item.description + " test " + item.id }}'`.
If you run it in debug mode:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item={'id': 'test1id', 'name': 'test1name', 'description': ''}) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "a": {
            "description": " test test1id",
            "id": "test1id",
            "name": "test1name"
        }
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "description": "",
        "id": "test1id",
        "name": "test1name"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'id': 'test2id', 'name': 'test2name', 'description': 'init'}) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "a": {
            "description": "init test test2id",
            "id": "test2id",
            "name": "test2name"
        }
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "description": "init",
        "id": "test2id",
        "name": "test2name"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'id': 'test3id', 'name': 'test3name', 'description': 'init3'}) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "a": {
            "description": "init3 test test3id",
            "id": "test3id",
            "name": "test3name"
        }
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "description": "init3",
        "id": "test3id",
        "name": "test3name"
    }
}
```

You just need to read the values back from `ansible_facts` you set.
The result should be registered temporarily and then convert the results to the original format with the updated values.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    a:
    - id: 'test1id'
      name: 'test1name'
      description: ''
    - id: 'test2id'
      name: 'test2name'
      description: 'init'
    - id: 'test3id'
      name: 'test3name'
      description: 'init3'
  tasks:
  - name: Update description in a
    when: a is defined
    set_fact:
      a: "{{ item | combine({'description': new_description}) }}"
    vars:
      new_description: '{{ item.description + " test " + item.id }}'
    loop: "{{ a }}"
    register: temporary_a

  - name: Results
    set_fact:
      a: "{{ temporary_a.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.a') | list }}" 

  - debug:
      var: a
```

Results:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => {
    "a": [
        {
            "description": " test test1id",
            "id": "test1id",
            "name": "test1name"
        },
        {
            "description": "init test test2id",
            "id": "test2id",
            "name": "test2name"
        },
        {
            "description": "init3 test test3id",
            "id": "test3id",
            "name": "test3name"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, in fact your right, i had a typo error during i write my question.
Your answer works well, i can have a good list at the end. I though we can do that without any additional step to set_fact but looks like we can't update inline during the loop.
thanks

Comment: You're welcome. You don't have to set additional fact. You can use `"{{ temporary_a.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.a') | list }}" ` directly.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to map objects items (dict), is to create a new empty list. And push to it in each iteration.

We push one item to a list by concatinating an array of one element

```yaml
list + [one_el]
```

In our case with combine to update

```yaml
new_a + [item | combine({'description': item.description + '-test-' + item.id})]
```

#### Giving the data

```yaml
- name: Set a
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    a:
      - id: "3"
        description: "Hola"
      - id: "6"
        description: "balo"
```

## We map using

```yaml
- name: Map list
  vars:
    new_a: []
  block:
    - name: Map items with update in new_a
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        new_a: "{{ new_a + [item | combine({'description': item.description + '-test-' + item.id})] }}"
      with_items: "{{ a }}"
    - name: Override a
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        a: "{{ new_a }}"
- name: Result output
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ a }}"
```

### Output

```json
TASK [Result output] *****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "description": "Hola-test-3",
            "id": "3"
        },
        {
            "description": "balo-test-6",
            "id": "6"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Inspired by

Inspired by the following answer https://serverfault.com/a/1035033/507537

```yaml
---
  - name: "Playing with Ansible and Git"
    hosts: localhost
    connection: local
    tasks:
      - name: A
        include_vars: vvsets.yml

      - set_fact:
          vvsets_new: []

      - set_fact:
          vvsets_new: "{{ vvsets_new + [new_value] }}"
        vars:
          new_item: { 'value': 'storageA'}
          new_value: "{{ item | combine(new_item) }}"
        loop: "{{ vvsets }}"

      - debug:
         msg: "{{ vvsets_new | list }}"
```

## Thoughts

- The way shown above. is simple and short more or less.

  - If the intended work is a bit large. One may better create a custom module with python. And have the full flexibility of python.

    - Just to be considered.